# ASP.NET profile privatization

Tags: c#, asp.net

While creating a new account for every user I want to create them so they have separate tables with names and uploaded files of their own, the upload is solved and working. Is this something really easy to do? Because I didn't find anything related to privatization. If anyone registers a person everybody else can see it.
            private DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection();

```
    // GET: Persoana
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Persoane.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Persoana/Details/5
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Persoana persoana = db.Persoane.Find(id);
        if (persoana == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(persoana);
    }

    // GET: Persoana/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Persoana/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersoanaID,Nume,Prenume,Slujba")] Persoana persoana)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persoane.Add(persoana);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(persoana);
    }
```

there is also edit and delete, I hope it helps you to help me.

Comment: I don't think you want to create new tables for every user. You want to set up some primary keys and only show the correct things for every user. For example SELECT * FROM table WHERE USER_ID = 1.

Comment: Yes, I want to show every user what he created/uploaded and nothing more.

Comment: Could you show some of the code you use to decide what to show to the users? And maybe how you set up the database / table?

Comment: A shot in the dark but would something like this work?   persoana = persoana.Where(s => (s.id.Contains(id));

Comment: will try in the morning, should I add this to all of them (create/edit/delete)?

Comment: I was thinking where you return the View or right before that. But you should try and see what happens, it's the best way to learn :)

Comment: no change yet, put into the Controller it doesn't do much. Will try and find a suitable location for it.

Comment: To keep the question going, in case anybody looks for this problem. It is still there and no solution yet. Will update every now and then I hope to answer my own question.